# I have the equation in frequency domain; How to go back in time and space domain with IFFT?

Tags: matlab, fft, interpolation, ifft

I have the solution of an equation (analytic solution) in frequency domain; How to go back in time and space domain with IFFT?

I try to input frequency samples (w, xi) in the equation and then to IFFT the results. However I am not sure if I did it correctly. I have read about interpolation, Dirichel etc. but i am not sure how to implement them. Can anybody guide me?

Thank you in advance.

Next I provide the two MATLAB files:
1.The main code
2.The function needed

Here is the main code:

```
clc;clear all;close all;
tic;
%The function in frequency domain 
%[wdf]=DynResp(0.01,w,xi); where 0.1 is constant, 
%xi is the x (space) in frequency domain and 
%w is the t (time) in frequency domain


Nt=1000; %number of samples for the frequency w
dw=1/196; 
w_max=dw*Nt;
w=[0:dw:w_max,-w_max+dw:dw:-dw];
t_max=1/(dw*2*Nt);
dt=t_max/(2*Nt);
t=[dt:dt:t_max];

Nx=1000; %number of samples for the frequency w
dxi=1/196;
xi_max=dxi*Nx;
xi=[0:dxi:xi_max,-xi_max+dxi:dxi:-dxi];
xi(xi==0)=100000000000; % for xi =0 the function goes to Infinity thus instead of 0 i give a bug number

x_max=1/(dxi*2*Nx);
dx=x_max/(2*Nx);
x=[dx:dx:x_max];

% Here i input the samples frequencies to the function (equation)

for i=2:2*Nx
   for j=2:2*Nt
       xiw_DynaFdom(i,j)=DynResp(0,w(j),xi(i));  
   end
end

% here is the inverse fourier transform of both xi and w to the x and t

xt_DynaT=(ifftshift(ifft2((wDynaFdom))))*Nx*Nt*dw*dxi/(pi^2);



% A plot in 3d
surface(x,t,real(wDynaT))
xlabel('x (m)') % x-axis label
ylabel('time(s)') % y-axis labe
zlabel('disp(m)') % y-axis labe

[max_idx] = max(max(wDynaT)); % Just the place of the maximum response in order to check the results

% A plot in 2d 

for i=1:length(w)
      plot(x,real(wDynaT(:,max_idx)))
end
```

Here is the function:

```
function [wdf] = DynResp(z,w,xi)
format long e;

P=15;m=10/9.80665;c=500/m;EE=40*10^6;II=1* 
(0.20^3)/12;EI=EE*II;k=120*10^3;l=50;
a0=0.1;v0=10;

wdf=(P*sqrt(2*pi)*exp(1i*((xi*v0+w)^2)/(2*a0*xi)))/(sqrt(1i*a0*xi)*(EI*xi^4+k+1i*w*c-m*w^2));

end
```

Answer (score -2):

In python using Scipy it can be done this way. I do not have Matlab to try.

```
from scipy import fftpack
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tr = np.cos(np.arange(100))
plt.plot(tr)
plt.title('original array')
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
fy = fftpack.fft(tr) #tr is some equally sampled array
amp = np.abs(fy)
phase = np.angle(fy)

# here you might apply some analysis filtering to amp or phase.
# amp : using multiplication, phase: using addition and substraction
tr_inverse = np.real(fftpack.ifft(amp * (np.cos(phase) + 1j*np.sin(phase))))
plt.plot(tr_inverse)
plt.title('recovered array')
plt.show()
```

[image]

`1j` is complex number sqrt(-1)

I think it is easy to convert from python to Matlab

Comment: Please do not answer in unrelated languages. I might as well answer this in Java or C++, but that's not what the OP asks for.

Comment: Besides, why do you decompose your complex signal into amplitude and phase, only to reconstruct it from those two in the next line? Seems like unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Thank you Khalil, 'tr' in your example is sampled in time domain ? Since in my problem I sampled my equation in frequency domain. So I dont need to use fy = fftpack.fft(tr). Am I right?

Comment: @EdmondMuho yes if your tr is already in frequency domain you do not need to use  `fy = fftpack.fft(tr)` but the amp and phase components should be available separately

Comment: Hi @Adriaan , thank for your notice. there is actually not much difference between matlab and numpy and scipy packages. Do, codes can easily be converted to matlab. After all the language is a tool, but most importantly is to convert the concept to some codes in a programming language and as said matlab and python are quite comparable. I am not asking op to mark my answer as accepted answer. give to give an idea till someone can give the code in Matlab which I do not have.

Comment: @Adriaan you decompose your signal to amp and phase. then you might do any filtering on the amplitude part. and finally apply ifft using the modified amp and phase to convert to time domain.

Comment: @EdmondMuho you are very welcome, hope it helps. by the way all code can easily be converetd to matlab by just removing import package prefix, e.g. `np.real = real, fftpack.ifft = ifft` etc. It is necessary to have both amplitude and phase spectrum to convert back to time domain. If there is no phase spectrum a random one must be generated assuming for example that the signal is zero phase.

Comment: @KhalilAlHooti I have only the analytic equation (solution) f_bar(w,xi) in frequency domain . So I input random samples of w and xi in f_bar in order to generate my spectrum. After this, I can calculate the amplitude and phase spectrum of f_bar and subsequently I can calculate the f(t,x) (space and time domain) by applying ifft using the modified amp and phase. Am I correct?

Comment: @EdmondMuho yes, exactly

Comment: @KhalilAlHooti Thank you so much, your above tips helped my to solve and verify my solution. Can you please provide me some information, i.e. a link, regarding the ifft(amp * (np.cos(phase) + 1j*np.sin(phase)), since this was the tip which helped me solve my problem. kind regards

Comment: @EdmondMuho you are very welcome, I am actually geophysicist and use fft and its application quite often. if you check this book at Appendix  A.1 in page 153, you will find the mathematical explanation specifically at equations A-5, A-6a and A-6b . https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ceu1x3JqYGUC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false . also I found a similar code in matlab at this website.  https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/24470-change-the-angle-of-fourier-transform-and-see-the-new-image